# Excel VBA - change text of CommandButton

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand why this VBA code returns run-time error 438:

```
        With Worksheets("DATA1").Shapes("CommandButton4")
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "In Stock"
        End With
```

I need to change the caption of the button.

The code is in Private Sub Workbook_Open().

Comment: What type of a Control (Button) are you talking about? Is it a Frame or an ActiveX control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you about the button type, but no answer. So, I will provide solutions for both types (Form or ActiveX). Please, check the next pieces of code:

In case of an ActiveX button (more probable, according to its name):

```
Sub changeActiveXButtonCaption()
   Dim bt As MSForms.CommandButton
   Set bt = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton4").Object
   bt.Caption = "In Stock"
End Sub
```

In case of a Form button, please check/use the next code:

```
Sub changeFormButtonCaption()
   Dim bt As Button
   Set bt = ActiveSheet.Buttons("CommandButton4")
   bt.Caption = "In Stock"
End Sub
```

Any of the above controls do not have a `TextFrame` property. Such a property, usually, belongs to a shape. Is your, so named, "CommandButton4" button a shape?

Comment: Sorry, I was out for some errands. I tried your first solution and it works great. Thank you very much for the awesome help. Really appreciated FaneDuru!

Comment: @Dolphin975 This means that the button in discussion is of ActiveX type...